# Change default IMAP folders

Tags: email, imap

On my HTC Evo 3D, my IMAP email account is using Trash folder for it's deleted items. My web mail AND my Windows Live Mail on my PC, using IMAP, is using Deleted Items folder. Can I change my phone to use Deleted Items?

This would also apply to sent items, it appears my phone uses Sent and everything else uses Sent Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend switching to [K-9 Mail](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.fsck.k9) if the default Email app can't handle this.

In K-9 Mail, once you've set up your account, long-press it and select `Account settings -> Folders`. On this page you can change the `Drafts folder`, `Sent folder`, `Spam folder` and `Trash folder` to your preferred ones.

Comment: tried tthat app, didn't like it.. but if the solution is a tthird party app, then I guess I'm stuck.

Comment: Is there any hope for us who cannot use this third-party application? (Nexus 7 does not have any alternative clients.)